# regular expression doesn't run in php, how to?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

i have this reg expression: `test(?:$|\s)` that does what i want

basically looks in a string like `test _test_ test  browser test.` and returns all `test` instances except `_test_`

the issue im having is that this below doesn't return no matches but regexr.com does

```
if (preg_match_all("/" . $word. "(?:$|\s)/i", $msg, $m)) {
    var_dump($m);
}
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: what is expected output and what are the rules?

Comment: Escape your `\s` to `\\s`.

Comment: Was just about to post the same - or use single quotes

Comment: @Braj basically looks in a string like `test _test_ test  browser test.` and returns all `test` instances exvept `_test_

Comment: @Patrioticcow Should `_test` be matched? What about `test_`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> returns all `test` instances except `_test_`

Try with Negative Lookahead

```
\b(?!_)test(?!_)\b
```

Here `\b` is used for word boundary.

Here is [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rI6yA4/16)

Sample code:

```
$re = "/\\b(?!_)test(?!_)\\b/i";
$str = "test _test_ test browser test.";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: Use a lookbehind please. This isn't JS. Also double escaping is a pain. Just use single quotes.

Comment: I don't have any idea about php. I know a little about regex  only. The is auto-generated code from demo site. change it as per the regex pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work with lookahead based regex:

```
$str = 'test _test_ test  browser test';
$word = 'test';
if (preg_match_all('/\b' . preg_quote($word) . '(?=$|\s)/i', $str, $m)) {
    var_dump($m);
}
```